# how to modify the version info of a hbase server or a region server?

Tags: hbase, ambari

We have a three-nodes HBase cluster(which was added by ambari 2.7.3), and the red error message: "3 nodes with inconsistent version" was always displayed on the HBase management page. After checking the source code of the HBase web management page, we found that the major version number of HBase was inconsistent with the version number of the RegionServer, which was the main reason for displaying this error message.

The version number of HBase is displayed as:'2.0.2.3.1.0.0-78, revision=', and that of RegionServer is displayed as:'2.0.2'.

May I ask if the version number of HBase or RegionServer can be manually configured? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . And add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.